# OpenCV "cvaux.h" equivalent

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv and am using OpenCV 3.0.0. I found an example using `include "cvaux.h"`. But, I want to use the new features rather than old C functions.

So, what is the equivalent hpp file for "cvaux.h"? Thanks

Comment: Look for a newer example. You can just "#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>"

Comment: so, opencv.hpp file contains cvaux?

Answer (score 1):

If your example is actually using `cvaux.h`, then you probably need to get a *newer* example. `cvaux` is related to **obsolete** C api and is now **deprecated**.

However, it can be found in: `#include <opencv/cvaux.h>`.

Note that most of the time you can just use the *"include all"* header: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`